# Update price on plus and minus buttons click in debute theme Shopify

Tags: javascript, html, shopify

I'm trying to change value of input and update the total price on click plus or minus  buttons. input is updating but total price is not updating in my codes.

```
<span class="qty-minus">-</span>
<input id="updates_large_{{ item.key }}" class="cart__qty-input" type="number" name="updates[]" value="{{ item.quantity }}" min="0" pattern="[0-9]* "data-quantity-input data-quantity-item="{{ forloop.index }}" data-quantity-input-desktop data-role="product-quantity-desktop">
<span class="qty-plus">+</span>
```

```
let qty_minus  = document.querySelectorAll("span.qty-minus");
let qty_plus  = document.querySelectorAll("span.qty-plus");
  
qty_minus.forEach(minus=>{
    minus.addEventListener("click", ()=>{

        if( minus.nextElementSibling.value;>1){
         minus.nextElementSibling.value--;
        };
    });
});
  
qty_plus.forEach(plus=>{
    plus.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
     plus.previousElementSibling.value++;
    });
});
```

Comment: The event listeners should be on the minus and plus spans. if qty_minus and qty_plus are those spans then what is that minus and plus you're adding an event to. The if(minus.nextElementSibling.value;>1) has semicolon before >.

Comment: Which element minus and plus refers to and also nextElementSibling?